# Conditional value in Zapier

Tags: zapier

I am using Zapier to write an email based on a field.

I have a field that has two values "ig" and "fb". I'd like to replace them respectively by "Instagram" and "Facebook".

[image: Screenshot of Zapier interface]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

There are two main ways to do that:

1. You can write a simple code block that, given `ig` or `fb` as input, return the full value you want to use
2. If you're not comfortable writing code, you can instead use a "Lookup Table" in "Formatter by Zapier", which produces a similar result. There's a step-by-step for that here: https://zapier.com/apps/formatter/help#using-the-lookup-table

---

Lookup table basic example. This is the same basic functionality as a lookup table

```js
// inputData is set up in the UI

const table = {
  ig: 'Instagram',
  fb: 'Facebook'
}

return {result: table[inputData.someFieldName] || 'Default Value'}
```

Comment: Thanks @xavdid can you please provide more details on where and how to write code block ?

Comment: I used "Lookup Table" but still curious to know how to use codes.

Comment: I've added a basic example